# `this` must be `void`

Tags: typescript, void

Experimenting with declaring a function that *must* be called with void this (`undefined`, `null` or `global`). And found an interesting thing. When declaring function with `this: void` it can be called with any `this`, but if I add some concrete type like `this: void | Function` (but it wouldn't work with `null`, `undefined`, `any`) it starts checking `this`.

[Code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#src=var%20x%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20void%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ax.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%20-%20why%3F%3F%3F%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20x.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20No%20error%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20y%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20Window%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ay.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%20%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20y.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20z%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20void%20%7C%20Window%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Az.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%20%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20z.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20a%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20void%20%7C%20null%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Aa.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Ok%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20a.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20b%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20void%20%7C%20Function%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ab.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20b.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok%0D%0A%0D%0Avar%20c%20%3D%20%7B%20f%3A%20function%20%28this%3A%20void%20%7C%20%28string%20%26%20number%29%29%20%7B%20%7D%20%7D%3B%0D%0Ac.f%28%29%3B%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%2F%2F%20Error%0D%0A%280%20as%20any%2C%20c.f%29%28%29%3B%20%2F%2F%20Ok):

```
var x = { f: function (this: void) { } };
x.f();             // Ok - why???
(0 as any, x.f)(); // Ok

var y = { f: function (this: Window) { } };
y.f();             // Error 
(0 as any, y.f)(); // Error

var z = { f: function (this: void | Window) { } };
z.f();             // Error 
(0 as any, z.f)(); // Ok

var a = { f: function (this: void | null) { } };
a.f();             // Ok
(0 as any, a.f)(); // Ok

var b = { f: function (this: void | Function) { } };
b.f();             // Error
(0 as any, b.f)(); // Ok

var c = { f: function (this: void | (string & number)) { } };
c.f();             // Error
(0 as any, c.f)(); // Ok
```

**I don't understand how does `void` works here.**

Comment: [`this` is a special variable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this).  It would be wise to not use it as a variable name.

Comment: @ErikPhilips `this` here is a fake parameter that come first in the parameter list of a function (specific to typescript and stripped out when transpiled to JS)

Comment: In ts 2.7 `void | null` also is error

Answer (score 0):

`void` is very strange type

```
var a:void = undefined; // ok
var b:undefined = a; // incompatible
```

In your example if all `void` types replace to `undefined` everything works as intended

Comment: No, it doesn't work with `undefined` - here is the code: `var d = { f: function (this: undefined) { } };
(0 as any, d.f)(); /* The 'this' context of type 'void' is not assignable to method's 'this' of type 'undefined'. */`

Comment: try to use `void | undefined` instead of `void` - it works perfectly